# compare two dataset together in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataset

Please I am working on a project, and here is the problem statement...

Search an element from dataset A through each column in dataset B
if an element is found from any columns in dataset B, return the result.

For example
Search a value name from column name in dataset A, if found in any column in dataset B
return
Value name column name found in columns name1,name2,name3(if its found in different column)

then do the same for each value in each column in dataset A.

I have tried and I wasn't getting it right. Please help:

here is my code

```html
import pandas as pd

# Load the data
table_a = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Holuwakenny/file/main/players_15.csv")
table_b = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Holuwakenny/file/main/fifa18_clean.csv")

# Get input from user for value to search for
value_to_search = input("Enter a value to search for: ")

# Get input from user for the row to search in


# Initialize an empty list to store the column names where the value is found
found_in_columns = []

# Iterate over each column in table B
for column in table_b.columns:
    # Search for the value in the column
    if value_to_search == str(table_a.iloc[row_to_search][0]):
        if value_to_search in table_b[column].values:
            # If the value is found, add the column name to the list
            found_in_columns.append(column)

# Print the result
if found_in_columns:
    print(f"'{value_to_search}' was found in column(s): {', '.join(found_in_columns)}")
else:
    print(f"'{value_to_search}' was not found in any column.")
```

Answer (score 1):

Some basic modifications should solve. Should iterate on columns in table_b and values on those columns. Getting this output on your dataset

'Cristiano Ronaldo' was found in column(s): Name

```
import pandas as pd

# Load the data
table_a = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Holuwakenny/file/main/players_15.csv")
table_b = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Holuwakenny/file/main/fifa18_clean.csv")

# Get input from user for value to search for
value_to_search = input("Enter a value to search for: ")

# Get input from user for the row to search in
#Don't need this

# Initialize an empty list to store the column names where the value is found
found_in_columns = []

# Iterate over each column in table B
for column in table_b.columns:
    # Search for the value in the column
    if value_to_search in table_b[column].values:
        # If the value is found, add the column name to the list
        found_in_columns.append(column)

# Print the result
if found_in_columns:
    print(f"'{value_to_search}' was found in column(s): {', '.join(found_in_columns)}")
else:
    print(f"'{value_to_search}' was not found in any column.")
```

Comment: From this solution, I want the value for the search to be from dataset A i.e Table_a.       if I remove table_a above, the code still works and it should compare both tables together. as the value should be from table_a